# Kotlin changing 2 scores when i press a button

Tags: java, android, kotlin, button

I hava two score and one button. I want to increase first score and 5 second later increase second score same button. There is code countdown timer

```
tt = object : CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
           override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
               binding.time.text = (p0/1000).toString()
           }
           override fun onFinish() {
               val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialogcard,null)
               val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
               alert.setView(dialogView)
               alert.setCancelable(false)
               alert.setPositiveButton("Go") { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                   if (!textChanged){
                       binding.teamName.text = arguments?.getString("teamName2")
                 //      binding.scoreText.text = secondTeamScore.toString()
                       textChanged = true
                   } else {
                       binding.teamName.text = arguments?.getString("teamName1")
                   //    binding.scoreText.text = secondTeamScore.toString()
                       textChanged = false
                   }
                   tt.start()
               }.show()
           }
       }
       tt.start()
   }
```

and here button code:

```
binding.trueButton.setOnClickListener {
                                    firstTeamScore++
                                    binding.scoreText.text = firstTeamScore.toString()
                                    secondTeamScore++
                                    binding.scoreText.text = secondTeamScore.toString()
}
```

how can ı do it

Comment: Take a boolean variable and toggle the value after every 5 seconds. Now check the condition in button click. Assume true for the first score and false for the second.

Answer (score 1):

One from the possible solutions is kotlin coroutines use. Example code:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).async {
        delay(5000)
        secondTeamScore++
        binding.scoreText.text = secondTeamScore.toString()
}
```